# Is it possible in Android programming to read embedded flash files from index.html

Tags: android, flash, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-plugins

Currently using PhoneGap with jQuery Mobile to create an application everything displays within the application except for the flash files.

```
package com.helloapp.namespace.myhelloworld;
import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyPhoneGapActivity extends DroidGap {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

}

}

I have have placed the following in the manifest xml

```
 android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

I've come across websettings and it does not work every time I program the code a line crosses out the     setPluginsEnabled(true)
I believe its deprecated.

```
WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
settings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
```

My flash files are embedded within my index.html

```
 <!--Embedded flash movie-->
  <p>
   <object width="710" height="493">
  <param name="movie" value="welcome.swf">
  <embed src="yaa/welcome.swf"
         width="710" height="493"> </embed>
</object>
  </p>
```

Is it possible to call embedded flash files from the index.html? Please take into consideration that I have already tried webview it keeps being deprecated, and I already have the necessary xml code.